# How to send requests to the discord api

Tags: discord

How could I send a request to the Discord API after someone authorizes my application?

I would like to send an request to get the users id and check if their email is verified, how would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide the solution that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the discord.js or discord.py.
[https://discord.js.org/](https://discord.js.org/#/) could help you.